# Expressing a number as the sum of n factors of n!

Tags: number-theory, factorial, integer-partitions

I recently solved a problem which asked me to show that all numbers under $n!$ can be expressed as the sum of at most $n$ factors of $n!.$ The proof of this is a simple application of mathematical induction. My question is: for a given $n$, what is the smallest number which cannot be expressed as the sum of $n$ factors of $n!$? Any n (not necessarily distinct) factors are allowed to be used. Therefore for $n=3,$ $12=6+6=6+3+3$ are both valid.

Clearly, any number larger than $n*n!$ cannot be expressed as such a sum of factors, as the largest factor of $n!$ is $n!$ itself. Therefore, we are able to see that such a number does indeed exist.

I have also tried to do the problem for small cases. For example, if $n=2,$ then the smallest inexpressible value is $5,$ and if $n=3,$ then the smallest inexpressible value is $16.$ Finally, if $n=4,$ the smallest inexpressible value is $65.$ I cannot seem to be able to generalize these values, however.

Comment: Your problem is unclear, could you give an example and tell us what you have done so far?

Comment: That the number exists should be clear since $n\cdot n!+1$ is an upper bound (*the largest sum of $n$ factors of $n!$ would occur when every factor is $n!$ itself which is strictly less than $n\cdot n!+1$*).  Beyond that, I don't expect there to be a nice closed form.

Comment: To be clear, can the factors be repeated in the sum? For example, with $n=3$, is $12$ achievable since $12=6+6=6+3+3$?  Or must they be distinct in which case $12$ is not achievable since the largest sum of *distinct* factors of $3!$ would be $6+3+2$?

Comment: By factors do you include $1$ because obviously any positive integer $n$ can obviously be represented as a sum of $n$, $1$'s

Comment: Yes, but $n$ is a fixed constant. This only shows that the number $n$ can be expressed this way.

Comment: Your inductive proof should give you a clue that since any number up to $2!$ can be expressed as one factor of $2!$ - i.e. a sum of $2$ factors is not required - any number up to $n!$ can be expressed as a sum of $n{-}1$ factors of $n!$. Implying that the least inexpressible number you are interested in is greater than $2\cdot n!$ and probably less than $3\cdot n!$.

Comment: @Joffan I showed through heavy computation that for $n>8,$ the least inexpressible number is greater than $3*n!$

Comment: @BrandonChen OK, that sounds plausible. Certainly given the least inexpressible number $X_k$ for $k!$, you know that $X_{k+1}\ge (k+1)X_k+1$, which actually gives your first results exactly. This doesn't exclude the possibility that this minimum value may be expressible, however.